# Best resource to learn SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I was a newbie to smartGWT and I was unable to find a complete resource for smartGWT in internet. Is there any good resources, where I can get to know about the complete potential of SmartGWT?

I have tried using the materials from the smartClient website and the showcases still I need some basic level resources to play with smartGWT

Comment: I strongly suggest to look into domino-ui. It is a state-of-the-art widget lib with a great support. https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui